# How to create an empty Series on pandas?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm learning about Series and I'm using VS Code to do excercises to learn it's usage, but when I typed this

```
 current_series_add = pd.Series()
```

in the terminal it shows me a message telling me that "Te default dtype for empty Series will be object instead of float64 in a future version"

**How can I specify a dtype?**

Answer (score 3):

As the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) say:

```
class pandas.Series(data=None, index=None, dtype=None, name=None, copy=False, fastpath=False)[source]¶

...

dtype : str, numpy.dtype, or ExtensionDtype, optional
    Data type for the output Series. If not specified, this will be
    inferred from data. See the user guide for more usages.
```

Example:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: pd.Series(dtype=int)
Out[2]: Series([], dtype: int64)
```